# I seek grammatical justification for "I did more than finish the job"

Tags: infinitives, comparatives

I see people say such examples as "I did more than finish the job", "He did more than win the game".

In such cases, "finish the job", which is a bare infinitival, occurs as the complement of "than". I wonder is there any justification in grammar for a bare infinitival to function as a comparative clause.

And what is the difference between such cases and those like "I did more than I finished the job"?

Comment: It seems to me these sentences need something more, e,g., He did more than finish the job—he figured out how to finish the entire project. I did more than finish the chapter, I finished the whole book. He did more than win the game, he demolished his opponents.

Comment: Yes, Xanne, you're making sense of the exact context I meant. Adding a supplement or not, however, the clause "He did more than finish the job" still stands on its own as a grammatical one. The focus of my question then is on the infinitive "finish the job" functioning as a complement of "than" in this comparative construction.